# Custom and Default Message Handler in Qt

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, logging

I want to use default Qt message handler while logging messages to a log file except qDebug. 
Here my solution, do you have any suggestion or what are the possible problems with this implementation?

Header:

```
#ifndef QLOGGER_H
#define QLOGGER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QDateTime>

class QLogger : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    QLogger();
   ~QLogger();

    static void start();
    static void finish();
    static QString filename;

private:
    static void myloggerfunction(QtMsgType type, const char *msg);

};

#endif // QLOGGER_H
```

Source:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDir>
#include <iostream>

#include "qlogger.h"

using namespace std;

QString QLogger::filename=QString("log.txt");

QLogger::QLogger()
{
}

QLogger::~QLogger()
{
}

void QLogger::start()
{
    qInstallMsgHandler(myloggerfunction);
}

void QLogger::finish()
{
    qInstallMsgHandler(0);
}

void QLogger::myloggerfunction(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
    QDir dir;
    dir.cd("LOG");

    QFile logFile(filename);

    if (logFile.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream streamer(&logFile);

        switch (type){
                 case QtDebugMsg:
                     finish();
                     qDebug(msg);
                     break;
                 case QtWarningMsg:
                     streamer << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() <<" Warning: " << msg <<  "\n";
                     finish();
                     qWarning(msg);
                     break;
                 case QtCriticalMsg:
                     streamer << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() <<" Critical: " << msg <<  "\n";
                     finish();
                     qCritical(msg);
                     break;
                 case QtFatalMsg:
                     streamer << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() <<" Fatal: " << msg <<  "\n";
                     finish();
                     qFatal(msg);
                     break;
        }
        logFile.close();
    }
    start();
}
```

Comment: I think it is a good implementation. However I would make it Singleton because there would be only one instance of it in a normal use case.
Technically speaking, I would make the constructor private and offer a static method that returns a static object of the class.

Answer (score 5):

Afaik this is not going to work, you are implementing the message handler function as a member function to a an object the signature of the function that `qInstallMessageHandler` takes is `void myMsgHandler(QtMsgType, const char *);`

You can either implement the function as a plain freestanding function or use a singleton with a static accessor e.g.

```
void msgHandler(QtMsgType type, const char * msg)
{
   Logger::instance()->handleMessage(type,msg);
}

class Logger
{
  static Logger* instance() {... }
  void handleMessage(QtMsgType type, const char* msg) { ... }
}
```

this gives you a function to use for `qInstallMsgHandler` and an object to wrap the logging

Comment: ı already use a static function, and it works. I wonder is there a more proper way.

Comment: not that I know of, I think the way they implemented this is really messy. But by having the instance as static and the actual function as a member you can keep a local state a little bit easier, otherwise you there is really no reason to create a class you might as well use a non-member function. Right now you are doing `cd` and `open` for each call to `qDebug()` and such