# Can I show qDebug() output in my Qt application?

Tags: debugging, qt, console

I use `qDebug()` commands throughout my project to throw information to the Output box in Visual Studio. Is there a way to make the `qDebug()` stream display in a widget in my application, like a test mode/error console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use qInstallMessageHandler to redirect the output of qDebug. For an example see the answer to the question "[Custom and Default Message Handler in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335331/custom-and-default-message-handler-in-qt)"